# "einwecken" vs "einmachen"?

Tags: etymology

Beide Verben

> einwecken

und

> einmachen

bedeuten dasselbe.

Offensichlich ist "Einmachen" von "machen" abgeleitet, aber vovon ist "einwecken" abgeleitet?

Comment: Gute Frage! Hab mich das selbst noch nie gefragt und jetzt ein wenig recherchiert.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Laut Wiktionary ist der Begriff "einwecken" ein Eponym, das heißt, dass er nach einer Person benannt wurde.

[**Johann Carl Weck**](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Carl_Weck) (1841 - 1914) war ein deutscher Unternehmer, der eine Gläser mit Dichtgummi produzierte. Seit 1901 verwendete man  in Publikationen seiner Firma das Wort *einwecken*, das dann 1907 in das Duden-Wörterbuch aufgenommen wurde.

Answer (score 1):

Die anderen Antworten sind alle richtig, daher habe ich zur eigentlichen Frage nicht viel mehr zu sagen. Allerdings fehlt in allen Antworten eine wichtige Information, die auch in der Frage nicht thematisiert wurde:

Das, was in Deutschland offenbar unter dem Markennamen *Weck* auf dem Markt ist, wurde in Österreich jahrzehntelang unter dem Markennamen *Rex* vertrieben. Die Marke wurde zwischenzeitlich vom Markt genommen, ist jetzt aber wieder zurück und scheint derzeit voll im Trend der Zeit zu liegen. Hier ist die Website dieser Marke: [rexglas.at](https://www.rexglas.at/)

Daher kennt man in die Wörter *»einwecken«, »Weckglas«, »Weckgummi«* usw. in Österreich so gut wie gar nicht. Verwendet man sie, rufen sie entweder fragende Blicke hervor oder outen den Sprecher als Deutschen.

In Österreich verwendet man stattdessen diese Wörter:

- einrexen [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/einrexen), [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/einrexen), [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/einrexen)
- Rexglas [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Rexglas), [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Rexglas)
- Rexgummi (Keine Wörterbucheinträge, aber [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Rexgummi) weiß ganz genau wie die Dinger aussehen)

Aus dem Verb *einrexen* hat sich sogar eine Redewendung entwickelt:

- das kannst du dir einrexen [ostarrichi.com](https://www.ostarrichi.com/wort/10661/einrexen_das_kannst_du_dir_einrexen), [Wörterbuch des Wienerischen](https://books.google.at/books?id=ldx2DwAAQBAJ&dq=das%20kannst%20du%20dir%20einrexen&q=das%20kannst%20du%20dir%20einrexen#v=snippet&q=das%20kannst%20du%20dir%20einrexen&f=false)
  Bedeutung: Das kannst du vergessen, das kannst du dir behalten / an den Hut stecken / in den A. schieben. Entstanden, weil eingerexte Lebensmittel oft jahrelang eingelagert wurden, und sie dann niemand mehr konsumieren wollte. Wenn etwas eingerext war, wollte es meist niemand mehr.

---

off-topic:

Dass gleiche Produkte in Österreich einen anderen Markennamen als in Deutschland haben, ist nichts ungewöhnliches:

- D: Aldi Süd = Ö: Hofer<sup>1</sup>
- D: Rewe = Ö: Billa
- D: Tesa = Ö: Tixo<sup>2</sup>

<sup>1</sup><sub>Das Logo von Hofer ist sogar dasselbe stilisiere *A*, dass auch Aldi-Süd verwendet, obwohl im Wort *Hofer* gar kein *A* vorkommt</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>Der Gattungsname für transparente Klebestreifen war in Österreich lange Zeit nicht *Tesa* sondern *Tixo.* Der Tesa-Hersteller Beiersdorf hat 1985 die Marke Tixo vom ehemaligen österreichischen Hersteller Kores gekauft und verkauft seine Klebestreifen in Österreich mittlerweile unter beiden Markennamen, daher beginnt auch hier allmählich der alte Gattungsname *Tixo* von *Tesa* verdrängt zu werden.</sub>

Comment: Interessant. Ich hätte mir bis jetzt unter *einrexen* nichts vorstellen können.

Answer (score 0):

"einwecken" ist von der Firma Weck abgeleitet. splattne hat Recht. Der "Weckgummi" stammt auch von der Firma Weck. Es ist ein starker, breiter, flacher Gummi, der zwischen das Glas und den Deckel gelegt wird. Mit Klammern werden beide zusammen gehalten und dann in einem großen Topf eingekocht - eingeweckt.

Das Wort *einwecken* dürfte in der jüngeren Generation heute kaum noch bekannt sein. Ich hätte mich auch nicht daran erinnert, wenn mich nicht vor ein paar Jahren, eine Bekannte deshalb etwas rüde zurecht gewiesen hätte. Am besten aus dem Vokabular streichen. *Einmachen* versteht jeder.

Von solchen Marketing-Wörtern gibt es noch viel mehr: Ein *Tempo* ist ein Papiertaschentuch (und keine Geschwindigkeit), ein *Tesa* ist ein Klebestreifen, ein *Aspirin* ist eine Kofpschmerztablette, ein *Hirsch* ist ein Fahrrad und ein *Jeep* ist ein Geländewagen. In Deutschland werden Markennamen immer wieder als Synonym für die Funktion verwendet. In der Schweiz ist das fast völlig unbekannt. Dort heißt das Tesa *Kläbi*. Also aufpassen und besser die allgemein verständlichen Wörter verwenden.

Comment: Ich kann der Empfehlung nicht zustimmen. Zum einen verstehe ich nicht, wieso das „[...] der jüngeren Generation heute kaum noch bekannt sein“ sollte. In meinem Familien- und Arbeitsumfeld gibt es mehrere Leute, ältere wie jüngere, die selber einwecken. Schon deshalb ist der Begriff für diese Tätigkeit immer wieder in aller Munde. Zum andern würde ich nie im Leben *einmachen* verwenden, weil das für mich ein Synonym für *einpullern* ist.

Comment: "einwecken" ist wie "Tempo" und "Tesa" allgemeinverständlich, zumindestens da, wo ich wohne. Warum der Rant in deinem letzten Absatz sein muß, erschließt sich mir nicht.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Siehe https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/einmachen.  Als Synonym für "einpullern" habe ich das noch nie gehört, mag aber regional so verwendet werden.

Comment: @tofro Ein Rant geht anders als der letzte Absatz.

Comment: @PaulFrost, siehe https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/einn%C3%A4ssen, Abschnitt „Synonyme“